"Gradle Build Failure: Error Resolving Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] in React Native"
I am working on a React Native latest project and trying to build and run the app on Android using the command: even i have reinstall new windows but it is still show me this
bash
Copy code
npm run android
However, the build fails with the following error:
vbnet
Copy code
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\android\settings.gradle' line: 2

What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']



java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-8eb3a248-d818-468e-9e2c-2c0038e9041a) to immutable location (D:\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\android.gradle\8.10.2\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10)
Steps I Have Tried
Cleared Gradle Cache:
Deleted .gradle folders in both the project and global directories (C:\Users<MyUser>.gradle).
Updated gradle-wrapper.properties:
Changed the Gradle version to:
ruby
Copy code
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip
Reinstalled Dependencies:
Deleted node_modules and reinstalled them with npm install.
Despite these efforts, the error persists.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
